# Using cell reference with COUNTIFS formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get this formula to work

```
=countifs(J6:J365, "=David & Victor", K6:K365, "=g3")
```

where `G3` is a date value (e.g., `02/24/14`).

I am trying to count the instances in my spreadsheet where David & Victor had any activity on that date. It is an on-going sheet so the date changes as the week progresses.  The formula works if I write it this way:

```
=countifs(J6:J365, "=David & Victor", K6:K365, "=02/24/14")
```

However this means that I have to modify the formula too many times.  Can someone help me figure out how else I can do this?

Answer (score 9):

Apply the following adjustment to your formula.

### Formula

```
=COUNTIFS(J6:J365, "=David & Victor", K6:K365, "="&G3)
```

### Screenshot

[image]